# Property Shadowing Issue

Tags: javascript, object, prototypal-inheritance, shadowing

I'm learning JS. Kyle Simpson in his Book, YDKJS, writes that:

> If a normal data accessor (see Chapter 3) property named foo is found
> anywhere higher on the [[Prototype]] chain, **and it's
> not marked as read-only ( writable:true)** then a new property called
> foo is added directly to myObject , resulting in a **shadowed property**.

```
function Foo(name) {
this.name = name;
}
Foo.prototype.myName = function() {
return this.name;
};
var a = new Foo( "a" );
var b = new Foo( "b" );
```

> In the above snippet, it's strongly tempting to think that when a and
> b are created, the properties/functions on the Foo.prototype object
> are copied over to each of a and b objects. **However, that's not what
> happens**. When `myName` is not found on a or b , respectively, it's
> instead found (through delegation, see Chapter 6) on Foo.prototype .
> Reference [Page 97](https://pepa.holla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/You-Don-t-Know-JS-this-Object-Prototypes.pdf)

To test the same, I created a property `val` on prototype object with value 1:

```
Foo.prototype.val = 1;
```

Since object `a` is prototype linked, I incremented this property by 1:

```
a.val++;
```

But when I executed following two lines:

```
console.log(a.val);   
console.log(Foo.prototype.val);
```

**Result:**

```
2
1
```

The result shows that a separate property `val` ****is created** on object** `a` with the incremented value 2, which seems contradicts (*that its delegated*) with his statement.

Where did I astray? Please guide

Comment: "_resulting in a shadowed property_" is a bit ambiguous, should be something like "shadowing the prototype property". Maybe that makes things more clear?

Comment: @Teemu I think its written this way because in the prototype chain if there is a property with the same name other than the prototype it self, then all of them will be shadowed and the one down in the chain will be considered

Comment: Not "_one down_", all the properties in the prototype chain with the same name are shadowed, and the value of the own property of the instance is read instead.

Comment: @Teemu yes that's what I mean

Comment: OK, now I can't see what exactly contradicts with what was written then? Shadowing is different from overriding, you can read a value of a prototype property when directly referring it, shadowing takes place when you set a value or explicitly define the property to the instance.

Comment: @Teemu 'a.val' evaluates to 2, while 'Foo.prototype.val' remains 1. That means, two separate properties (val) exists on object 'a' and 'Foo.prototype' respectively. But according to Book, it just reads 'val' from 'Foo.prototype' object and the property is not created on object 'a'

Comment: Nope, it's shows you exactly what is said in the book: "_when a and b are created ... [`myName` function] is instead found ... on `Foo.prototype`_". In your example you've set the value: `a.val++;`, and that makes the shadowing.

Comment: As you pointed out, the book says: _"If a normal data accessor property named `foo` is found anywhere on the `[[Prototype]]` chain, and it's not marked as read-only ( writable:true) then a new property called `foo` is added directly to `myObject`"_. Performing `a.val++` is more or less the same as doing `a.val = a.val + 1;`, the `a.val =` part creates an "own property" directly on `a` because `val` on `Foo.prototype` is not read-only. So you now have a property on the prototype (the one you created with `Foo.prototype.val = 1`, and one as an own property ("shadowing the prototype one)

Comment: @Teemu The Book says:  "However, that's not what happens". So according to Book, 'a.val++;' should not make shadowing and is instead found on 'Foo.prototype'.

Comment: @NickParsons I totally agree with what you have said. But read the para that says 'However, that's not what happen'. Or tell me, to what does this line refer to?

Comment: Again no, you're doing a different action, in the book, the created value was never modified after definition. You're setting the value of the property via the instance with `++` operator. Define `val` as a function and log `a.val === Foo.prototype.val`, you'll get `true`. Then redefine `a.val = 1;` . When you do the same comparison after redefinition, you will get `false`.

Comment: @Sadiq Kyle is saying that `myName` isn't created as a property directly on the `a` and `b` objects when doing `new Foo(...)`, the property `myName` and its function remain on the prototype. But you're doing something different with your code, as you are assigning a property called `val` to `a` (with `a.val++`), so `val` gets created as a property directly on `a`. In a similar way, if you were to also assign and did `a.myName = 'x'`, now `myName` is a property directly on `a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confusing what happens with values on the prototype when assigning a value vs when creating an object using the constructor function.

For example, take the book's first example:

```js
Foo.prototype.myName = function() {...};
var a = new Foo( "a" );
var b = new Foo( "b" );
```

As Kyle outlines in his book, when using the `new` keyword to create objects `a` and `b`, the values from `Foo.prototype` aren't created as properties directly on `a` and `b` (ie: own-properties), but instead, `a` and `b`'s `[[Prototype]]`s point to `Foo.prototype`, which is where `myName` is accessed.

In your example code, you're firstly creating a property called `val` on the prototype:

```
Foo.prototype.val = 1;
```

and then incrementing `val`. This increment is what then creates an own-property on `a`. To show what's happening in more detail, the below is begin performed:

```js
 v--- creates an own-property directly on `a` 
a.val = a.val + 1;
         ^--- accessing 1 from `Foo.prototype.val`
```

The `a.val =`  component of the above creates an own property called `val` directly on the `a` object, and the `a.val + 1` is accessing the value you had previously set with `Foo.prototype.val = 1;` via accessing `a` via the `[[Prototype]]`, and then adding `1` to it. As you're effectively doing an "assignment" here, you end up creating an own property on `a`, which is a different operation from what the excerpt shown from Kyle's book is doing, where he is just creating a new object using the `new` keyword.